# JQUERY and JAVASCRIPT OOP

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, plugins, prototype

I have a jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#expand_label_object").on("click", function(){ 
$(this).toggleClass("col-3");
$(this).toggleClass("col-12"); 
$("#expand_label_info").toggleClass("hidden");
});
});
```

It simply uses toggleClass to give me the desired output.

I have a lot of elements that I want to use this function on, the problem is using the procedural way of programming I will have to write this function for each element I would like to perform the function on. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#expand_Date_object").on("click", function(){
$(this).toggleClass("col-3");
$(this).toggleClass("col-12");
$("#expand_Date_info").toggleClass("hidden");
});
});
```

As you can see the only thing that changed was the #expand_label_object and #expand_label_info.

Does anyone have any advise for how I can go about creating an object in javascript that will be able to perform the work of this function and then I can simply instantiate a new object of this "class" that can perform the task on the new information provided in example #expand_Date_Object.

Or should I write a plugin for jquery that will handle this.
If so how?

1. Can I create an object and prototype that object?
2. Should I use a constructor?
3. How will I be able to handle the jquery library in a prototype framework?

Comment: Show basic html structure. Good chance can do this simply with one event handler and some classes or using other attributes

Comment: That's a general question. Please post a sample of the markup and specify what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, do not try to throw OOP at arbitrary problems. All you need here is a basic function declaration with the selectors as the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a named function, call function setting `this` to current clicked element utilizing [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), pass selector string as parameter to function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function handleClick(selector) { 
    $(this).toggleClass("col-3");
    $(this).toggleClass("col-12"); 
    $(selector).toggleClass("hidden");
  }   

  $("#expand_label_object").on("click", function() { 
    handleClick.call(this, "#expand_label_info")
  });

  $("#expand_Date_object").on("click", function() { 
    handleClick.call(this, "#expand_Date_info")
  });

});
```

Comment: Curious about reason for "downvote"? How does `javascript` at post not meet requirement described at OP?

Comment: never seen طحان like u .. Best regards .

Comment: @Nitin Which portion of Answer do you believe required editing?

Comment: @Nitin Two extra spaces are not necessary to convey details of approach. What was your reason for initial "downvote"? _"According to stack rules, I cannot upvote your answer unless you edit it"_ Can you provide link to this rule?

Comment: @Nitin Did not think you downvoted, asked if you downvoted. Is that a good reason to cast "downvote"?

Comment: @Nitin Updated Answer by including link to `Function.prototype.call()` within explanation of Answer. Can you provide link to the rule that you referenced?

Comment: @guest271314 great! I upvoted your answer as this is a good working solution.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you want an elegant code based on OOP paradigm ; if so , you could take advantage from **ES6** syntax:

## 1. Build Abstract  API :

```
   //- -- JQuery Class

   class $Class{
         constructor(selector,parent){
             this.selector=selector;
             this.parent= parent;
         }
         get element(){
             return (this.parent)?$(this.selector,this.parent):$(this.selector);
          }
         on(event,callback){

              this.element.on(event,callback);
         }

   }

    //Common service (contains static methods)

        class CommonService{

            static toggle1(htmlElement){
                 $(htmlElement).toggleClass("col-3");
                 $(htmlElement).toggleClass("col-12");
                 $("#expand_Date_info").toggleClass("hidden");

             }
         }
```

## 2.  Use API :

```
 var exp_label=new $Class('#expand_label_object');
 exp_label.on('click',function(){ CommonService.toggle1(this)} ) 

  // the same of the other code , it will be : 
 var exp_date=new $Class('#expand_Date_object');
 exp_date.on('click',function(){ CommonService.toggle1(this)} )
```

Hope this OOP that you target.

Comment: Looks like a case of  bloating the code needlessly for something simple

Comment: @charlietfl  : i knew. however this is the requirements of question owner ... So , if there is worst-practices , it is the question not the answer .. What you say? What about ? AM  I right ?

Comment: No... Op was asking if it was practical and it's a waste of effort that over complicates  a simple situation. OP has created an XY problem

Comment: I respect your opinion.. However who asks seems has nostalgia to OOP & i should respect his emotion .

Comment: @guest271314: Really really, don't let me cry. plz .. I love some programming paradigms & i put myself in the postion of question owner ... So emotional.. Ahhhh

Comment: I believe the best answer should be given for a problem, so other developers can learn from it. If the requested solution is not optimal, there is no harm in providing a better or futureproof solution.

Comment: @Nitin What do you mean by "best" and "better"? How are these terms measured in relation to the actual `javascript` utilized at an Answer?

Comment: The best or better solution should be decided upon by fellow developers with more experience who know the drawbacks of each solution. Only by putting all possible solutions on the table, can one decide which is the best.

Comment: From the comments I gather that oop will not be the best approach here,

Comment: @GustavCoetzee : That's why i make effort to reach this opinion